# gcc and Visual studio compiler interaction

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, cl

I have one project which must to be compile on Visual Studio compiler (Project 1) and another project with gcc compiler (Project 2).

i'm wondering how both projects can be connect so it will be possible for Project 1 (on VS) to call an API function implemented on Project 2.

Both pojects need to run on the same process and I have both sources codes.

Where and how such connection should be done?

Comment: The question is rather broad. You can either implement Inter Process Communication (named pipes, sockets, COM on Windows, etc) and have 2 cooperating processes, or port one of the project to the other environment and compile everything in one single project.

Comment: Thanks but as wrote before, i want to use one process only and cant change the enviroment/compile on the same project

Comment: So you have to use Dynamic Link Libraries. Windows API allow to explicitely load a DLL acquire the address of a function and call it. COM can also use DLLs.

Comment: Looking for any solution which can meet the requirement

Comment: What's wrong with the DLL API? AFAIK you can use it to get the address of a function from an EXE file provided it is exported.

Comment: Will lool into it, Thanks!!! :)